# How to implement parametrization for complete test using python pytest

Tags: python-2.7, pytest

I am using pytest fixture in one function inside my test class to implement parametrization. Test class runs for below parameters 5 and 4 but  in single run.
How do I ensure that my test runs separately for both the parameters.

Code :

```
import pytest
@pytest.fixture(params=[5,4],scope='session')
def data(request):
    return request.param

def test_ddt(data):
    print data

def test_ppt():
    a=12
    print a
```

Output : 
test_param.py .5 .4 .12

I am expecting this output : .5 .12 .4 .12
Is it possible ?

Comment: From your above code `test_ppt` is no where related to your parameterized tests and hence your output is expected and is correct. However to get your expected out pass data to your test_ppt method something like `test_ppt(data)` this should work.

Comment: @santosh why not make an answer out of the comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your above code `test_ppt` is no where related to your parameterized tests and hence your output is expected and is correct. However to get your expected out pass `data` to your `test_ppt` method something like `test_ppt(data)` this should work